# Control degree of parallelism with std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Is there a way to explicitly set/limit the degree of parallelism (= the number of separate threads) used by `std::async` and related classes?

[Perusing the thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) hasn’t turned up anything promising.

As close as I could figure out, `std::async` implementations (usually?) use a thread pool internally. Is there are standardised API to control this?

For background: I’m in a setting (shared cluster) where I have to manually limit the number of cores used. If I fail to do this, the load sharing scheduler throws a fit and I’m penalised. In particular, `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` holds no useful information, since the number of physical cores is irrelevant for the constraints I’m under.

Here’s a relevant piece of code (which, in C++17 with parallelism TS, would probably be written using [parallel `std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)):

```
auto read_data(std::string const&) -> std::string;

auto multi_read_data(std::vector<std::string> const& filenames, int ncores = 2) -> std::vector<std::string> {
    auto futures = std::vector<std::future<std::string>>{};

    // Haha, I wish.
    std::thread_pool::set_max_parallelism(ncores);

    for (auto const& filename : filenames) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, read_data, filename));
    }

    auto ret = std::vector<std::string>(filenames.size());
    std::transform(futures.begin(), futures.end(), ret.begin(),
            [](std::future<std::string>& f) {return f.get();});
    return ret;
}
```

From a design point of view I’d have expected the `std::execution::parallel_policy` class (from parallelism TS) to allow specifying that (in fact, this is how I did it in the framework I designed for my master thesis). But this doesn’t seem to be the case.

Ideally I’d like a solution for C++11 but if there’s one for later versions I would still like to know about it (though I can’t use it).

Comment: why are you using `std::async` to begin with? the thread-pool implementations are non conforming anyway and standard conforming ones will open a new thread for each task. either way, it sucks

Comment: @DavidHaim It seemed the easiest solution. I’m trying to write as little code as possible to just process these function calls in parallel, and I had hoped I could get away with just using the standard library. Apparently not.

Comment: we will be forced to write solutions ourselves as long as the committee insist on wasting time on core language features instead of important modern utilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. `std::async` is opaque, and you have no control over it's usage of threads, thread pools or anything else. As a matter of fact, you do not even have any guarantee that it would use a thread at all - it might as well execute in the same thread (potentially, note @T.C. comment below), and such implementation would still be conformant.

C++ threading library was never supposed to handle fine-tuning of OS / hardware specifics of threads management, so I am afraid, in your case you will have to code for the proper support yourself, potentially using OS-provided thread control primitives.

Comment: "and such implementation would still be conformant" Not without heroic efforts with thread-local variables.

Comment: Note I’m using `std::launch::async` — this guarantees use of a (“as if”) new thread (§30.6.8/3.1).

Comment: @T.C. yes, didn't think about it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, T.C. comment above notwithstanding, physical parallelism is not part of "as if" rule.

Comment: @SergeyA I’m *quoting* the standard here. It literally says “as if in a new thread”. For what it’s worth. And, to be honest, I’m totally fine with that restriction (otherwise I wouldn’t use `std::async`), but I absolutely **must** set an upper limit.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, sure. But this is a definition of 'as if' i am pointing to. It doesn't cover performance aspects.

Comment: @SergeyA As I said, that’s fine. My question isn’t about performance but about correctness.

Answer (score 5):

As other people have noted, `std::async` doesn't let you do this.

**Yet** (but see the May 2022 update at the end of the answer)

You're describing one of the simpler use-cases of [Executors](http://wg21.link/P0688r0) which are currently still bouncing around the design-space of C++ Standardisation, specifically right now in [Study Group 1: Concurrency](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee).

Since reading WG21 standards proposals can be a slog, they authors have helpfully linked to both a [prototype *header-only* reference implementation](https://github.com/executors/issaquah_2016/tree/rebind-prototype/rebind_prototype) and [some example code](https://github.com/executors/issaquah_2016/tree/rebind-prototype/rebind_prototype/examples).

It even includes a static thread pool, and an example of almost exactly what you want:
[async_1.cpp](https://github.com/executors/issaquah_2016/blob/rebind-prototype/rebind_prototype/examples/async/async_1.cpp)

```
#include <experimental/thread_pool>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

namespace execution = std::experimental::execution;
using std::experimental::static_thread_pool;

template <class Executor, class Function>
auto async(Executor ex, Function f)
{
  return execution::require(ex, execution::twoway).twoway_execute(std::move(f));
}

int main()
{
  static_thread_pool pool{1};
  auto f = async(pool.executor(), []{ return 42; });
  std::cout << "result is " << f.get() << "\n";
}
```

---

Thank you to @jared-hoberock for pointing me at [P0668R0](http://wg21.link/P0688R0) as the much simpler followup to [P0443R1](https://wg21.link/P0443R1) which I had referenced in an earlier version of this answer.

This simplification has been applied, and now there's both a paper describing the rationale ([P0761R0](http://wg21.link/P0761R0)), and a much simpler version of the standard wording in [P0443R2](http://wg21.link/P0443R2).

---

As of July 2017, the only actual guess I've seen on delivery of this is: Michael Wong, editor of the [Concurrency TS](https://isocpp.org/std/status) --- the standardisation vehicle for Executors --- feels "[confident that it will make it into C++20"](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/10-06-17-whats-in-cpp-20-and-cpp17-final-score-card).

---

I'm still getting Stack Overflow Points™ for this answer, so here's a May 2022 update:

Executors didn't land in C++20.

"A Unified Executors Proposal for C++" reached revision 14 ([P0443R14](https://wg21.link/p0443r14)) in 2020, and a new paper `std::execution` ([P2300R5](https://wg21.link/p2300r5)) is proposed as a follow-on; See sections [1.8](https://wg21.link/p2300r5#intro-is-not) and [1.9](https://wg21.link/p2300r5#intro-compare) for the reasons for the new paper and differences from P0443.

Notably:

> A specific thread pool implementation is omitted, as per LEWG direction.

The "Do in a thread-pool" example from `std::execution` looks like:

```cpp
using namespace std::execution;

scheduler auto sch = thread_pool.scheduler();

sender auto begin = schedule(sch);
sender auto hi = then(begin, []{
    std::cout << "Hello world! Have an int.";
    return 13;
});
sender auto add_42 = then(hi, [](int arg) { return arg + 42; });

auto [i] = this_thread::sync_wait(add_42).value();
```

There's a lot to process here. And the last decade of work has pretty much abandoned "`std::async` and related classes", so perhaps the actual answer to this question is no longer

> **Yet**

but

> **No**, and there *never* will be. There'll be a different model where you can do that instead.

c.f. [the Motivation section of P2300R5](https://wg21.link/p2300r5#motivation)

> `std::async`/`std::future`/`std::promise`, C++11’s intended exposure for asynchrony, is inefficient, hard to use correctly, and severely lacking in genericity, making it unusable in many contexts.

[P2453R0](https://wg21.link/P2453R0) records the rough feelings of the LEWG participants around this current approach, and also how it interacts with the existing Networking TS, i.e. Asio, which has [its own concurrency model](https://wg21.link/P2444R0). *My* reading of the polls and comments says neither is likely to land in C++23.

---

I'm still getting Stack Overflow Points™ for this answer, so here's a June 2023 update:

Executors didn't land in C++23.

P2300 looks to be getting some traction, it's up to [P2300R7](https://wg21.link/p2300R7), and there's both an [experimental reference implementation](https://github.com/NVIDIA/stdexec) and further standardisation exploration based on it, e.g., [P2882R0](https://wg21.link/P2882R0) and [P2500R1](https://wg21.link/P2500R1)+[P2690R1](https://wg21.link/P2690R1). That latter link suggests P2300 is targeted for C++26, which was also [LEWG's weak consensus last year](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1054#issuecomment-1159801626), albeit with half the participants and [fewer comments](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2575r0.html#p2300r5-stdexecution).

Comment: Upvote for the great take on p2300